# How to implement a simple notification system in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to implement a simple notification system in Rails(no gem). Let's say I have a blog app using Devise for auth, and on a post posted by user A(logined) there is a "Like" button, if another user, user B clicks on that button, I would like to notify user A with a simple notification like: "User B liked your post!".

I'm new to Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible since Rails 5 and Action Cable. A good tutorial can be found here:

https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable

It involves creating a 'channel' which each user subscribes to, however it's far easier to run through a tutorial like the one above rather than have me explain step by step. The above is for creating a chat room, so you'd just swap the new message for a new notification.